# Trying for google+ sign in with php codeigniter it gives error invalid_client

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-plus

I am firstly trying for `Google+` sign in. followed all steps up to creating client ID and secret key but it's giving me error i.e invalid client. what are the reasons I checked out multiple sites but cannot understanding actual reason of this error. Following is my script.

```
function loginCallback(result) {
   if (result['status']['signed_in']) {
        var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
            'userId': 'me'
        });
        request.execute(function(resp) {
            alert(resp.name);
            var email = '';
            if (resp['emails']) {
                for (i = 0; i < resp['emails'].length; i++) {
                    if (resp['emails'][i]['type'] == 'account') {
                        email = resp['emails'][i]['value'];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: probably have to turn off that stupid security thing they added...  Less Secure apps,  https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: are you using this on localhost? I've only been able to get it work on production!

Comment: i am working on production . my above problem is solved  but now its giving  new error that  domain isn't  verified , actually i have verified our domain. what should do now

Comment: Enabling "Allow less secure apps" is not a solution to this problem. You should not enable it and reduce the security of your account.

Comment: @swati that is an different issue and you should create a new question for it. You should also post an answer here as to how yo fixed your problem or close this question.